# Error Installing ROS on Windows10

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edition: Windows 10 Home
Version: 1903
OS build: 18362.720
System Type: 64-bit operated system, x64-based processor
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8130U CPU @ 2.20Ghz

Following the installation detailed in http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

When I execute choco upgrade ros-melodic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0

I get the following error below. (However, executed all previously commands fine with no error messages)

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
ros_core: No definition of [rosbag_migration_rule] for OS [windows]
rospack: No definition of [python-catkin-pkg-modules] for OS [windows]
diagnostic_common_diagnostics: No definition of [hddtemp] for OS [windows]
trajectory_msgs: No definition of [rosbag_migration_rule] for OS [windows]
desktop: No definition of [common_tutorials] for OS [windows]
simulators: No definition of [stage_ros] for OS [windows]
joint_trajectory_controller: No definition of [code_coverage] for OS [windows]
joystick_drivers: No definition of [wiimote] for OS [windows]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  vcpkg: Vcpkg is not installed
ERROR: rosdepInstall.bat failed.
The upgrade of ros-melodic-desktop_full was NOT successful.
Error while running 'c:\opt\chocolatey\lib\ros-melodic-desktop_full\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (c:\opt\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - ros-melodic-desktop_full (exited -1) - Error while running 'c:\opt\chocolatey\lib\ros-melodic-desktop_full\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348689/error-installing-ros-on-windows10/) by [dts1](https://answers.ros.org/users/53305/dts1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-07**:
Please provide links to any documentation or tutorials you are trying to follow. Additionally I would also add the build nr of your Windows 10, and whether you encountered any issues following any of the previous steps.

There isn't sufficient information for anyone here to help you.

**Comment by [dts1](https://answers.ros.org/users/53305/dts1/) on 2020-04-07**:
Thank you for the feedback. Just provided documentation link, build nr of windows, and no errors from previous steps.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-08**:
Similar question: #q348731.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the answer https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/203

---

Originally posted by [gaspard_bourgeois](https://answers.ros.org/users/53025/gaspard_bourgeois/) with karma: 26 on 2020-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you may look insde of you
c:\opt\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log

and it also sayes:
Vcpkg is not installed.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some of the rosdep keys errors are benign - ROS on Windows' meta package contains the actual packages.

However, the vcpkg error is concerning. Did you run this command from a visual studio command prompt?

---

Originally posted by [OoeyGUI](https://answers.ros.org/users/37999/ooeygui/) with karma: 186 on 2020-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-04-08**:
I've tried to reinstall ROS on Windows just to reproduce OP's question and I've got the same error as well. I believe there was no such error occurred when I installed it last time around February. Perhaps it's worth creating an issue on GitHub as another similar question has just been raised on ROS Answers.

**Comment by [dts1](https://answers.ros.org/users/53305/dts1/) on 2020-04-08**:
Yes I ran the following command from a VS command prompt (x64 Native Tools Command Propmpt for VS 2019- in Administrator mode).

**Comment by [gaspard_bourgeois](https://answers.ros.org/users/53025/gaspard_bourgeois/) on 2020-04-08**:
I have the same problem for 2 days now, I also tried to [install it from source](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/Build/source.html) without success.

Edition: Windows 10 Entreprise: 1809 OS build: 17763.1039 System Type: 64-bit operated system, x64-based processor Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60Ghz 1.80Ghz

**Comment by [gaspard_bourgeois](https://answers.ros.org/users/53025/gaspard_bourgeois/) on 2020-04-08**:
I ran this file : C:\opt\chocolatey\lib\ros-vcpkg\tools\install.wrapper.bat
It installed Vcpkg in c:/opt/ directory and added it to my path
I succeed finishing the installation but I have some problems with rospack package on my installation.

**Comment by [Sean Yen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37768/sean-yen/) on 2020-04-08**:
For whoever runs into this, please kindly share your logs in this GitHub issue https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/203, so we can have a better understanding of what's happening...